# Can philosophy clarify these strange expressions?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, paradox

I remember these two observations from when I was ten:

- the 2nd number is 2, but he 2nd from last is only 1 number away from
  the last
- (a+b)^2 =/= (a^2)+(b^2) BUT (10cm)^2 = (10^2)+(cm^2)

Does it make sense to ask why these seem paradoxical? I'm not saying that they are paradoxical, in any way, so am not asking for proof that they aren't. I'm asking if analysing sentences like this can tell us anything.

Comment: In physics (and geometry) units behave multiplicatory. That means (10cm)² = 10² x cm² =100 squarecentimetres (an area), whereas 10cm + 10cm = (10+10)cm = 20 cm (a length).

Comment: Because 10cm is **not** 10+cm... "6 eggs" are not 6 + eggs but it is a little bag with eggs inside.

Comment: Because the 1st number you count to is the last backwards. It does seem strange if you confuse counting with measurement: because then the start, at zero, wouldn't be the end backwards.

Comment: The second number is only one number away from the first.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it make sense to ask why these seem paradoxical?

It makes sense, but the answers are trivial.

> - the 2nd number is 2, but he 2nd from last is only 1 number away from
>     the last

This is just one of the many examples of imprecision in the language. It would be less confusing if we would say something like *"second counting backwards"*. But this isn't a true philosophical paradox.

> - (a+b)^2 =/= (a^2)+(b^2) BUT (10cm)^2 = (10^2)+(cm^2)

In the term (10 cm)² there is a multiplication sign implied, **not** a plus sign. So your second equation is actually wrong.

(10⋅cm)² is unusual but correct. Which is why it isn't a paradox.